# Starting rviz, failed to initialize ogre, cannot find RenderSystem_GL.so

Tags: ros, rviz, gentoo, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### Found an answer. See my answer below (guess I can't accept my own)

Setting up things on my (gentoo) desktop.

Command line output just about says everything:

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
Failed to initialize Ogre: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library RenderSystem_GL.  System Error: RenderSystem_GL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /home/murph/ros/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)
[ERROR] [1298662054.238455770]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library RenderSystem_GL.  System Error: RenderSystem_GL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /home/murph/ros/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)                                                                                                                                                  
murph@murph ~/ros $ find . | grep -i RenderSystem_GL.so
./visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.so
./visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/build/lib/RenderSystem_GL.so
```

My hardware:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV620 [FirePro 2260]

And my drivers:
x11-drivers/xf86-video-ati version 6.13.1

[edit]
I found this: https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=49372&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20

Which sounds similar. I copied RenderSystem_GL.so,
Plugin_OctreeSceneManager.so, and Plugin_ParticleFX.so up a folder as indicator (one by one as they were pointed out as missing), but now it cannot find Plugin_CgProgramManager.so which I do not have anywhere.

[edit 2]
When doing 'make' after 'make wipe' on the ogre subtree, I see this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The following OPTIONAL packages could NOT be located on your system.
-- Consider installing them to enable more features from this software.
+ OpenGL ES: Support for the OpenGL ES 1.x render system 
+ cg: C for graphics shader language 
+ POCO: POCO framework 
+ tbb: Threading Building Blocks 
+ Doxygen: Tool for building API documentation 
+ CppUnit: Library for performing unit tests 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice that cg is included there. So perhaps the configure scripts can't find my Cg libraries (they are installed)? I'm no cmake wizard, though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9206/starting-rviz,-failed-to-initialize-ogre,-cannot-find-rendersystem_gl.so/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-25**:
Could you update your question to include your graphics card and driver version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the ogre setup doesn't search the right locations for you Cg libraries on Gentoo. Set this before you run make wipe && make in the ogre subfolder.

```
export Cg_HOME=/opt/nvidia-cg-toolkit
```

Also, it seems that for some reason gentoo systems end up putting some of the .so files in the wrong folder, so we'll need to move them afterwards.

export Cg_HOME=/opt/nvidia-cg-toolkit 
cd ~/ros/visualization_common/ogre

Of course, now it segfaults. But I'm sure that's something different.

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1